# Timing issue causes alternate HTTP POST request to fail while using ESP32

Tags: http, arduino, timeout, http-post, esp32

I am using an ESP32 to make a http POST request. The problem is if the requests are made within less than 4 seconds, every post request is a success. But if the delay between consecutive requests in greater than 4 seconds, then every **alternate** request succeeds with a code of 200. What could be the problem, I have posted the code below, along with a screenshot of the serial monitor.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

HTTPClient http;
const char *ssid = "DIGISOL";
const char *password = "Praj@Nsc#123";
//int lcount = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(500);

  WiFi.begin(ssid,password);
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
}

void loop() {
  //lcount++;
  String httpr = "https://support.nscpl.dev/testgalv3/php/esp32.php" ; 
  String data = "ABCD";
  http.begin(httpr);
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.setTimeout(15000);
  String postData = "key1=" + data; 

  int httpResponseCode = http.POST(postData);

  if (httpResponseCode > 0) {
    Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    String response = http.getString();
    Serial.println(response);
  } else {
    Serial.print("HTTP Request failed. Error code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  }
  http.end();
  delay(5000);
}
```

The output of the serial monitor is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqgXf.png)
`

I tried changing the timeout and the delay to try various combinations. But with delay greater than 4 seconds, consistently every alternate request fails. Is it a timeout issue? Cause even if the timeout was set to 15 seconds, when the request fails, it returns -2/-5 immediately without waiting for the response.

Comment: Hi @Soham Baste - welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question and copy and paste the output of the serial monitor into it. It's text, there's no need to provide it as an image. Images can't be searched and won't work correctly with screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

These are the error codes from the HTTPClient.h

```
#define HTTPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED  (-1)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_SEND_HEADER_FAILED  (-2)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_SEND_PAYLOAD_FAILED (-3)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED       (-4)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_LOST     (-5)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_NO_STREAM           (-6)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_NO_HTTP_SERVER      (-7)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_TOO_LESS_RAM        (-8)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_ENCODING            (-9)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_STREAM_WRITE        (-10)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_READ_TIMEOUT        (-11)
```

I am not entirely sure about that 15 sec timeout and the delay(5000), maybe try removing the delay(5000) and use a non-blocking method like this

I'll just post the relevant bits, this will have an initial 5 sec delay before the first post but if after that it keeps working ok than you can play around and adjust it

```
unsigned long delay_timer = 0;
int delay_interval = 5000; //<-- change this to whatever delay you want

void setup() {
  // your code as it is
}

void loop() {

  if(millis() - delay_timer >= delay_interval){
  
     String httpr = "https://support.nscpl.dev/testgalv3/php/esp32.php" ; 
     String data = "ABCD";
     http.begin(httpr);
     http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     http.setTimeout(15000);
     String postData = "key1=" + data; 

     int httpResponseCode = http.POST(postData);

     if (httpResponseCode > 0) {
       Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
       Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
       String response = http.getString();
       Serial.println(response);
     } else {
       Serial.print("HTTP Request failed. Error code: ");
       Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
     }
     http.end();
     
     //delay(5000); //<-- remove this

     delay_timer = millis(); 
   }
}
```